# How to get the value of Gather input widget in Twilio function "let val = event.widgets.Mortgage_info.Digits.value;"?

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio, twilio-node

I can't get the value of my gather input widget in Twilio function, I always get an error
[image]

This is the name of the gather input widget in Twilio studio
[image]

This variable is not working.
let val = event.widgets.Mortgage_info.Digits.value;

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
     const got = require('got');
    
     
     
     
     got('https://cyan-sparrow-7490.twil.io/assets/mortgage.json').then (response =>{
         
         
         const mort = JSON.parse(response.body);
         let mortgageData = mort.feed.entry;
         let mortgageIdTest = mort.feed.entry[900].gsx$mortgage.$t;
         
         //Begin filter code
         let val = event.widgets.Mortgage_info.Digits.value;
         let index = mortgageData.findIndex(function(item, i){
            return item.gsx$mortgage.$t === val
         });
         
         //End filter code
         
         let mortgageSpecificData = mort.feed.entry[index];
         let mortgageId = mort.feed.entry[index].gsx$mortgage.$t;
         let borrowerName = mort.feed.entry[index].gsx$name.$t;
         let lenderName = mort.feed.entry[index].gsx$lender.$t;
         let recordDate = mort.feed.entry[index].gsx$recorddate.$t;
         let lendAmount = mort.feed.entry[index].gsx$amount.$t;
         let neededData = `Borrower ${borrowerName}\nYou loan with ${lenderName}\nClosed on ${recordDate}`
         
         
         
         console.log(val);
         console.log(index);
         console.log(neededData);
         callback(null,neededData);
         
     });
     
     
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the value of `{{widgets.Mortgage_info.Digits}}`` into the Twilio Function via the Run Function Widget Function Parameters.

You can see how this may work by looking at this code example.

[Using Run Function widget in Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-run-function-widget-studio)

Comment: Hi Alan, after I console.log the return is null. How to get the value of the mortgage info?
I define it like this 
let mortgageInfo = event.mortgage_info;
is that correct?
I already put the key= mortgage_info and value= {{widgets.Mortgage_info.Digits}} in widget function.

Comment: Can you put this code at the top of your function, to console log out the event object and see what is coming in? Also, look at the Studio Execution logs (left side of the screen) and then click on an execution. See what the Digits value is to make sure you are using the correct liquid syntax to access it.

 Object.keys(event).forEach( thisKey => console.log(`${thisKey}: ${event[thisKey]}`));

Comment: After I put the code it logs for an error http://prntscr.com/127h8wb

Comment: Alan, the key and value are now working in Twilio function.